Why does anaconda shows a different python version then python.org
In my Anaconda-Navigator for every environment is python 3.11.9 installed and in the naviagtor on the environment tab is only 3.11.9 for update offered (as of 03-Oct-2024).
Why is anaconda offering only 3.11.9 instead of 3.12.6 offered on python.org
(On MacBook Pro M3pro MacOS 14.6.1; Anaconda 2.6.3)
On my Laptop with all environments deactivated, is python 3.12.6 installed.
I did run conda update on conda, anaconda and python, but in all environments conda updates only to 3.11.9.

When you install miniconda, for example, you can specifically choose the Python version, cf. here.
I suspect that a full anaconda installation is similar. Which anaconda version did you choose? https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/
EDIT: Based on this answer, Python 3.11.9 is installed in your base envvironment. To use Python 3.12.6 instead, you can do something like this:
env_name="myenv" && conda create -n "$env_name" python=3.12.6 -y &&
conda activate "$env_name"

Replace env_name by whatever the name of your new environment should be.
EDIT 2: To answer the question why anaconda comes shipped with python 3.11 instead of python 3.12, my suspicion is that the OP does not have the latest anaconda version installed. Hence, for a Mac M3Pro that the OP, I would recommend uninstalling anaconda and re-installing it from this link, which comes with python 3.12 shipped.

I use anaconda 2.6.3

Thanks. I did not see that you had already put this in your question. I edited my answer, let us know how it goes.

Hi Imhan, I do know how to install versions with conda. My question is why Anaconda3 lists in environments not the latest stable phython version.
Highest vesion offered in Anaconda is 3.11.9 and Python.org lists 3.12.6.

Thanks for the clarification. I added an "EDIT 2".

Thank you Imhan, as I need a package that still requires 3.11, I will not yet upgrade, but will your hint when the package upgrades

You could also re-install anaconda, and use a new conda env for python 3.11 (cf. my EDIT 1 for that). In that case, your base env would come shipped with python 3.12. However, it is ultimately your decision. Please consider accepting the answer.
